# App Store事前登録受付の方法

Tags: ios, app-store

Super Mario Runのように事前登録を受け付ける設定は可能でしょうか？

ストアでは下記のように配信の事前予告が行われています。
[image: 予約配信のサンプルプレビュー]

Comment: 一般に公開はされておりません。……が、法人なら頼めばやってくれるのかも？

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。直接問い合わせてみます！

Comment: ネガティブ評価受けてますが、iOSの開発者としての質問なので私は特に問題は感じられません。ただ、このまま質問が残ってしまうのもよろしくないので、問い合わせた結果を自己回答し承認頂けると、より良い質問となるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appleにdeveloperとして質問したところ、現在は限定的に特定のアプリケーションでのみ利用可能な機能ということでした。

追加情報です。
App Storeの上部にデザインを適用しているアプリがあると思いますが、これも同じく特定のアプリケーションでのみ利用可能な機能とのことでした。